# Node.js showing TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
RV =(typeof (myresult.CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D2.INSTPARAM[0].VALUE !== 'undefined')) ? myresult.CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D2.INSTPARAM[0].VALUE : 'NA';
```

in the above code i want to get the value , if the key does not exists it should take 'NA' but iam getting below error

**Error**: - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'INSTPARAM')

Comment: chain them with optional chaining `(?.)` so if anything is undefined it would say "NA".

Comment: @dream player can you show me a example for above case?

Comment: `myresult.CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D2.INSTPARAM[0]?.VALUE`

Comment: without ternary operator `myresult.CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D2.INSTPARAM[0]?.VALUE ?? 'NA';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myresult.CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D2?.INSTPARAM[0].VALUE ?? 'NA';

using the option chaining.

Comment: does this fixed your issue?